# whats the performance of chaining swift's array higher order functions?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, functional-programming

I'd like to chain a filter, then map on an array, but I am concerned about the performance. what I would like to understand is that is swift's compiler intelligent enough to optimize this operation to make it run in a single loop rather than two loops if I did it like this:

```
private func getSearchResponsesss(from bookResults: SearchBooks.Search.BookResults) -> SearchBooks.Search.Response {
    let presentableBooks = bookResults.books
        .filter { !$0.pictures.isEmpty }
        .map { book -> SearchBooks.Search.Response.BookPresentable in
            let image = book.pictures[0]
            let presentableBook = SearchBooks.Search.Response.BookPresentable(pictureKey: image,
                                                                              pictureStatus: .downloading,
                                                                              name: book.name,
                                                                              price: book.price)
            return presentableBook
        }
}
```

or should I do like this to save on performance?

```
private func getSearchResponsesss(from bookResults: SearchBooks.Search.BookResults) -> SearchBooks.Search.Response {
    var presentableBooks: [SearchBooks.Search.Response.BookPresentable] = []
    for book in bookResults.books {

        if book.pictures.isEmpty {
            continue
        }
        let image = book.pictures[0]
        let presentableBook = SearchBooks.Search.Response.BookPresentable(pictureKey: image,
                                                                          pictureStatus: .downloading,
                                                                          name: book.name,
                                                                          price: book.price)
        presentableBooks.append(presentableBook)
    }
    return presentableBooks
}
```

Comment: Try measuring the time it takes yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is not smart enough to understand the functions in the standard library and come with ways to optimize their calls.

However, the problem with chaining is not the double iteration. From performance perspective iteration is not a big problem. The real problem are memory implications. Every time you call `.filter` or `.map`, the result is a new sequence, therefore we need memory to store the temporary sequence.

To alliviate this, Swift arrays have [.lazy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687859-lazy) property, which enables you to chain lazily, without creating intermediate results and without multiple iterations:

```
bookResults.books
    .lazy
    .filter { !$0.pictures.isEmpty }
    .map { ... }
```

As another solution, you can always merge `filter` and `map` using `compactMap`:

```
let presentableBooks = bookResults.books
    .compactMap { book in
        guard let image = book.pictures.first else { return nil }
        return SearchBooks.Search.Response.BookPresentable(
            pictureKey: image,                                                                             
            pictureStatus: .downloading,
            name: book.name,
            price: book.price
        )
    }
```

Comment: @naif I didn't want my answer to sound condescending, I tried to update the wording a bit. However, I am pretty sure that this has to be always property of the implementation, not a property of the compiler.

Comment: thanks for the great answer! I would like to also apologize for being too sensitive. I am fasting, so I haven’t eaten in a while. Ramadan Kareem.